# can't retrieve all rows from a table

Tags: php, mysql, web, fetch

I've tried the past hour to figure a way for the server to recognize if a user already owns a similar row in my MySQL DB

can any of your guys help me...

here is the code ive done by now

```
$nummer = $_GET['a'];
$klasse = strtoupper ( $_GET['b'] );

$kid = $nummer . '.' . $klasse;

$result = $db->query("SELECT kid FROM Kcode WHERE sid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
$resa = $result->fetch();

$b = strtoupper ( $resa['kid'] );
$a = $kid
$c = $_SESSION['id'];



if ($a !== $b){
echo "insert";
} else {
echo "already exists";
}
```

ok to explain deeper what the different get commands is:

- `$_GET['a']`=a letter retrieved from the previous page
- `$_GET['b']`=a number retrieved from the previous page

"kid" wich i wanna select is a row in my Kcode table, the problem is that there are several kid's that i want to compare to `$a`... but when i try this way it only retrieve the last created.

thx for your time

edit:
as said in the comment i want to compare `$kid` with mysql rows called kid `WHEN sid=$_SESSION['id']`.

Comment: it seems `$kid` should be `$_SESSION['id']`

Comment: no cause i want to compare `$kid` with the all mysql rows called kid `WHEN sid=$_SESSION['id']`.    btw $kid is what they postet on the previous page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve multiple rows, you need to put your `fetch` in a loop:

```
$exists = false;

while($resa = $result->fetch()) {

    $b = strtoupper ( $resa['kid'] );
    $a = $kid
    $c = $_SESSION['id'];

    if ($a !== $b){
        //echo "insert";
    } else {
        $exists = true;
        //echo "already exists";
    }
}


if($exists){
{
    echo "already exists";
} else {
    echo "insert";
}
```

Is this what you were trying to do?

Now, if all you are trying to do is to see if a row exists, you should modify your query:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT kid FROM Kcode WHERE sid='".$_SESSION['id']."' 
                      AND kid='$kid'");
```

Since you are getting `$kid` from you `GET` parameters, you need to clean it up first, to prevent SQL injection.